# Build a JSON dynamically with data stored in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, each

I need to build a `JSON` dynamically.

The `JSON` works if it is not dynamic.

Here is a working example but the `"@id"` and `"name"`are not dynamic  :

```js
var el_2 = document.createElement('script');
el_2.type = 'application/ld+json';

el_2.text = JSON.stringify({
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": [{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 1,
    "item": {
      "@id": "https://example.com/",
      "name": "Home",
    }
  }, {
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 2,
    "item": {
      "@id": "https://example.com/text_1",
      "name": "Text_1",
    }
  }, {
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 3,
    "item": {
      "name": "Text_2",
    }
  }
  }]
});

document.querySelector('head').appendChild(el_2);
```

I need to make it dynamic.

I use `jQuery’s each()` function to loop through each element of the breadcrumb.

Then, I push the element into an array:

```js
var array_breadcrumb_text = [];
$('.region-breadcrumb .breadcrumb li').each(function(index, value) {
  array_breadcrumb_text.push($(this).find("a").attr('href') + ' : ' + $(this).text());
  // output of links and text is  correct
  console.log(array_breadcrumb_text[index]);
});
```

I don’t know how to use this array in order to build the JSON.

Generally, I use a `foreach` loop but since I am inside of the `JSON.stringify()`, I can't use a `foreach` loop, because I have a syntax issue.

Here is the breadcrumb HTML structure

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li>
                  <a href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
                  <a href="/text_1">Text_1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="active">
                  Text_2
          </li>
 </ol>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got enough information to realise you CAN do what you are trying to do.

So I assume you want this:

```js
var el_2 = document.createElement('script');
el_2.type = 'application/ld+json';
var bread = {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": []
}

$('.breadcrumb li').each(function(index) {
  var item = {}
  var href = $(this).find("a").attr('href');
  if (href) item["@id"] = href // OR location.protocol+"//"+location.host+href;
  item["name"] = $.trim($(this).text()); 

  bread.itemListElement.push({
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": index + 1,
    item
  })
});

el_2.text = JSON.stringify(bread);
console.log(JSON.stringify(bread,null,2))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/text_1">Text_1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    Text_2
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I've checked the JSON inside `<script type="application/ld+json"></script>` and it perfectly matches the example in my question. That's why I upvote and mark as correct your answer. But it doesn't pass Google test tools. If I copy paste the JSON code outputted by your code in  `<head>` and remove the JS, it passes the Google test tools. I've spent a few hours on this and I don't understand for now. I used the same principle to generate the JSON for my local pages and in this case it passes the Google test tools. Need to check again everything. I'll get back to you when I'll found a solution.

Comment: The only thing I found for now, if I comment `//item` in `bread.itemListElement.push({});`I can see in Google test tools all structured datas for locale pages, logo,  breadcrumb, social profile. Of course, there are errors for breadcrumb (item is missing) but Google found the datas.

Comment: Try the update - perhaps the @ID MUST be before name

Comment: I've already tried this but I will try again (need to double check ;-)

Comment: I've spent a few hours on this issue and even if your code is correct, it doesn't pass structured data google testing tool (https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/). My conclusion for now is we can't use an `object` (`item` in your code). Even if I use `item` outside of the `each()` and if I assign a simple value without iterate over the DOM elements, it doesn't work. It works for my local pages because I only use variables and not `object`. Need to find an alternative, create this on server side I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I would build out a function something like:

```
function createListItem(el, index) {
    var $el = $(el);
    var data = { 
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": index,
        "item": {}
    };

    data.item['@id'] = $el.find("a").attr('href');
    data.item.name = $el.text();
    // add image etc.

    return data;
}
```

This builds out the `ListItem` parts of your data structure. You can build it like:

```
var array_breadcrumb_items = $('.region-breadcrumb .breadcrumb li').map(createListItem);
```

Once that's sorted you can:

```
var result = JSON.stringify({
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": array_breadcrumb_items
});
```

Essentially the easiest way to break up a JSON structure is to break it down into the repeatable parts, assemble them and then pass the result through the `JSON.stringify` as late as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var bread = {
      "@context": "",
      "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
      "itemListElement": []
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 1;
        $('li[class*="breadcrumb-item"]').each(function(i,j){
         var href = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
         if (!href) href = location.href;
          bread.itemListElement.push({
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": counter,
            "item": href,
            "name": $.trim($(j).text())
          })
        counter++;
        });
        var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(bread);
        $('#dynamicJSONLD').append(jsonStr);
    });
</script>   
<script id="dynamicJSONLD" type="application/ld+json"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).